# Mongo Template Criteria query for addition of two column

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive

I want to write one query where lastReceivedTime(time in epoch) plus some duration(some millisecond like 60000) should greater than current time

query.addCriteria(
Criteria.where(HandlerConstant.LAST_RECEIVED_TIME + HandlerConstant.SOME_DURATION).lte(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())
);

But this is not working, it is concatenating these two string then trying to find that column.

Answer (score 0):

How do you store your time in the database?
A common approache is using Date ( LocalDateTime in java ), and with this approach you can convert your epoch time in LocalDateTime, perform the desire operations and then getting the epoch time back again